# Released App on App Store but says your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Released App on App Store but says your device isn't compatible with this version.

Tried with an old Note 3 that isnt updated but then tried with a Samsung s7 that is up to date and still get the same. It doesn't actually show on the play store I found it on google and used the link and got that message.

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.random.com"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 4
        versionName "4.0"
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
}



    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Is there any quick way to change this so it is backward compatible with all versions even older ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the minimum sdk level to 25, thereby excluding any devices below api 25

`minSdkVersion 25`

You can change this to a lower api level (ie api 21 or 16), but make sure your app is able to support this and behaves as expected.

For reference, here's the list of Android api levels https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers

Comment: Great thanks, what would you suggest I put as rhe minimum sdk version?

Comment: 21 is a pretty safe bet. you get about 70% of android users.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `minSDKVersion` as `25`. This means that devices starting Android Nougat are compatible with this app. You should change it may be API version `14`. That should cover most of the devices

You can find device build numbers here https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers

You can find Android OS usage stats here from Google
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html